# JW Player 6.10 Firefox : two escape key press is needed to exit fullscreen mode with HTML 5 player

Tags: firefox, jwplayer

When using JW Player 6.10 on Firefox and trying to exit full-screen mode, two escape key press is needed to exit full-screen mode with HTML 5 player.

This can actually be reproduced on JW Player web site :
http://www.jwplayer.com/wizard/

On their home page they embedded player in iframe to avoid this second escape key press issue... But full-screen icon is not well updated.

The bug seems to be related to JW Player itself because I cannot get the issue with JW Player 6.2.

How can I fix this issue without iframe in 6.10 version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that will be fixed in 6.11.

Comment: No problem, it will be out soon.